# Qt changed image opacity in stylesheet

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I need to changed opacity of button's image or background image for single image in stylesheet or other way.

I want set the button three state through single image, like that

```
QPushButton{
 image:url("xxx.png") 70%
}
QPushButton:pressed{
 image:url("xxx.png") 100%
}
QPushButton:disabled{
 image:url("xxx.png") 40%
}
```

I have checked image style which Qt support, it seems that i can't achieve it.

I know i can changed image in other software such that Photoshop,but I want to implement it with single image, it is easier and fewer resource required.

It doesn't must do it in stylesheet, maybe some other way like that palette which i don't know it's work mechanism.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Well, if by chance your problem is equal to managing `QPushButton`'s opacity (talking about background image), you could make something out of [QGraphicsOpacityEffect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html).